# Localstorage saves only last object (vanilla Javscript)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to make a app with book list in OOP but I have a problem with saving a list in localstorage.I made that user can add his books and now I want to save this into local storage. I made a array and I'm saving objects into it but something not work. I'm getting only latest object and I don't know why.

piece of js:

```
    var title = document.querySelector('input#title').value;
    var author = document.querySelector('input#author').value;
    var status = document.querySelector('select').value;
    var table = document.querySelectorAll('.table')[1];
    var book = new Book(title, author, status);
    obj.push(book);
    localStorage.setItem('Array',JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: How obj is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the previous localStorage item with the key 'Array'.

The **setItem()** method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name and value, will add that key to the given Storage object, or update that key's value if it already exists, so the previous localstorage item will be updated in your case..
If you want to solve it, you need to use the values from previous attempts, you need to use a unique key.
maybe something with running id like

```
localStorage.setItem(`Array-${id}`,JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same key everytime you use setItem, localStorage will overwrite that value. I think the problem that you are encountering has to do with how you initialize obj array. If you have a function that saves the books list/array to the localStorage then make sure you initialize obj outside that function. Check out the example below.

```js
function Book(title, author, status) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.status = status;
}

var obj = []; // <- initialize obj array here instead

function addBook(title, author, status) {
  // var obj = []; <- if obj is initialized within the function it will be a new empty array every time, which is why localStorage only shows the latest item.

  var book = new Book(title, author, status);

  obj.push(book);

  localStorage.setItem('Array', JSON.stringify(obj));
}

addBook('Harry Potter: Order of Phoenix', 'JK Rowling', 'Available')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are initializing `obj` with previous values:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Array'));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do somthing like get the Array value from your local then add the item there.

```js
const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Array')) || [];

class Book {
  constructor(title, author, status) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.status = status;
  }
}

document.getElementById("push_item").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("push");
  var title = document.querySelector('input#title').value;
  var author = document.querySelector('input#author').value;
  var status = document.querySelector('select').value;
  var table = document.querySelectorAll('.table')[1];
  var book = new Book(title, author, status);
  array.push(book);

  localStorage.setItem('Array', JSON.stringify(array));
});
```

```html
<input id="title"></input>
<input id="author"></input>
<select >
  <option value="1"/>1
  <option value="2"/>2
</select>

<button id="push_item">Push</button>
```